# Cambiar src de imagen conJS

Tags: javascript

Necesito cambiar el src del ícono de menú hamburguesa al clickerarlo. Este es el código:

```
    const menuBtn= document.querySelector(".menuIcon");
    menuBtn.addEventListener("click", cambiarBoton);
    function cambiarBoton(){
        if(menuBtn.src === "images/assets/burger.svg"){
            menuBtn.src = "images/assets/close.svg"
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Y ese código funciona?, ¿da algún problema?, por favor lee [ask]

Comment: No has aclarado lo que te preguntan en el comentario. Sabemos qué necesitas hacer pero no sabemos nada de qué problema tienes con ese código

Comment: Hola! Disculpen soy nuevo en esto, gracias por las sugerencias. El código no muestra ningún error por consola pero simplemente no cambia la imagen.  Es como si no entrara en el condicional if, porque hago console.log dentro de la fn pero antes del if, lo toma. Dentro del if no sucede nada.

Answer (score 1):

Para cambiar la imagen desde jquery puedes hacer :

Con Jquery

```
function cambiarBoton(){
    if(menuBtn.src === "images/assets/burger.svg"){
        $(".menuIcon").attr("src","images/assets/close.svg");
    }else{
       $(".menuIcon").attr("src","images/assets/burger.svg");
    }
}
```

Con JavaScript

```
  function cambiarBoton(){     
        if(menuBtn.src === "images/assets/burger.svg"){         
            document.getElementsByClassName("menuIcon").src="images/assets/close.svg";     
        }else{         
            document.getElementsByClassName("menuIcon").src="images/assets/burger.svg";     
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Gracias! Pero para este proyecto no tenemos permitido el uso de jQuery :(

Comment: Prueba de esta forma, javascript

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar la respuesta para que se ajuste a la pregunta del OP. Además, el código en los comentarios es ilegible :P

Comment: Gracias Gerardo, sigue sin funcionarme de todos modos, no logro ver el error.

Comment: Que error es el que te da?

Comment: El código no muestra ningún error por consola pero simplemente no cambia la imagen.  Es como si no entrara en el condicional if, porque hago console.log dentro de la fn pero antes del if, lo toma. Dentro del if no sucede nada.

Comment: Creo que debe tener que ver con la ruta de la imagen. En este caso la carpeta images es hermana del archivo scripts.

Comment: Pero estan en el mismo directorio?, si no encuentra el if como dices pueba pasar las lineas que estan arriba de tu funcion,dentro de ella, tambien pongo como estan llamando a tu funcion cambiarBoton()